# extract data issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table where my env_value = 202052 (2020 is the YYYY and 52 is weeks in a year)
 In the year end after it hits Dec last week which is 202052 then it should start with new year week 
 which is 202101 (env_value)
 With the query i tried it is giving me output as 202053 but i am expecting to see 202101.i am unable to 
 figure out how to do.

```
  CREATE TABLE env_sys(
    [env_cat] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [env_opt] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [env_value] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL)

    insert into env_sys 
    values( 'REPORT_EXTRACT', 'LAST_FILE_PROCESSED' , '202052')

  select 

    rtrim(case when substring(env_value,5,2) between '01' and '08'
    then substring(env_value,1,4)+'0'+cast(cast(substring(env_value,5,2)as int)+1 as char(2))
    when substring(env_value,5,2) between '09' and '52'
  then substring(env_value,1,4)+cast(cast(substring(env_value,5,2)as int)+1 as char(2))
 else
  substring(env_value,1,3)+cast(cast(substring(env_value,4,1)as int)+1 as char(1))+'01' 
 end) 
from env_sys
where env_cat = 'REPORT_EXTRACT'
and env_opt = 'LAST_FILE_PROCESSED'
```

Comment: I would recommend that you abandon this approach, and instead just store your date information in a bona fide date column.  If you want to extract the year and year-week, SQL Server has plenty of ways to do that.

Comment: Can you suggest me the best way to do this.

Comment: But there are 365-366 days in a year. That comes to 52.14/52.29 weeks; so you're *going* to always get a week 53. There's always at least 1 day that is in an extra "week".

Comment: FYI-
Our calendar is always 1-52 and then restarts at 01 when the next fiscal year hits.So there won't be any 53 weeks